# validation is not correct when no elements type in the confirm password text box

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to check the validation of the password. In below when I try to type something in password text field and if I ignore the confirm password text field, still it can be submitted. But if I type something in confirm password text field it'll check it with  the password text field, whether the inputs are same or not.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aLr8gtf/3/)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="enableForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">New password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Confirm_password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#enableForm').bootstrapValidator({
                container: '#messages',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    password: {
                        enabled: false,
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The password is required and cannot be empty'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        enabled: false,
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The confirm password is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            identical: {
                                field: 'password',
                                message: 'The password and its confirm must be the same'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            // Enable the password/confirm password validators if the password is not empty
            .on('keyup', '[name="password"]', function() {
                var isEmpty = $(this).val() == '';
                $('#enableForm')
                .bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators', 'password', !isEmpty)
                .bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators', 'confirm_password', !isEmpty);

                // Revalidate the field when user start typing in the password field
                if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
                    $('#enableForm').bootstrapValidator('validateField', 'password')
                    .bootstrapValidator('validateField', 'confirm_password');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: i think its working fine check fiddle

Comment: Seems it working correctly. But it doesn't.

Comment: Its not allowing to submit if password is wrong? What you are expecting ?

Comment: when both are same(password and confirm password) it will have a green color tick at the end of the text field. If you type something for the password and ignore the confirm password field(type nothing) and check it. Still it shows green color tick at the end of confirm password field.

Comment: trry updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8aLr8gtf/4/

Comment: @PardeepDhingra just enter something in new password and check. There are green color ticks in both of the fields(new password and confirm password). But actually it should indicate red icon in the confirm password box(Because we didn't enter anything yet).

Comment: try this will work, glyphicons are coming.. i have to leave now..will check that tomorrow https://jsfiddle.net/8aLr8gtf/6/